# How to write an element reference to a window.open function?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, window

So, I started working with "window.open" in javascript, and got stuck pretty quickly.

In my example code, there is a p tag with the id "reference", and a button that calls a function meant to write that p tag to a new tab.

How would I properly reference the p tag and write it to the new tab?

So far, I've only gotten "[object HTMLParagraphElement]" using the code below...

HTML

```
<p id="reference">This is some placeholder text meant for another page.</p>

<button onclick="createTab()">Create Tab</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function createTab() {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "Test");
  myWindow.document.write(document.getElementById("reference"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following instead of document.write:

```
myWindow.document.appendChild(document.getElementById("reference"))
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.